# pass dynamically created data to d3 through playframework

Tags: javascript, scala, d3.js, playframework

this is the scenario :

we have a web server (**playframework**) which based on user requirements produces a set of `json data`, this data then needs to be passed to javascript function.
at the moment I can use it only if I retrieve data from a static files, but not quite sure how to do it for the dynamic data:

to demonstrate what I have at the moment:

**javascript file:**

```
tlFIle = d3.select("#myID").attr("data");
d3.json(tlFIle , function(error, json) {
//some function 
});
```

**index.html.scala:**

```
...
<div id="myID" data="/assests/files/mydata.json"> 
...
```

So is there a way to use dynamically created json data instead of using the static files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You give a path, D3 does not care if the json behind this path is dynamic or static as far as it can get some json.

Just give a path to a dynamic resource.

```
@jsonFilePath = @{routes.MyController.getDynamicJson()}

d3.json(@jsonFilePath , function(error, json) {
//some function 
});
```

Comment: ty. I just needed to do some work around it, but it worked at the end :)